# select2 4.0 brings older list in suggestion with query method and minimumInputLength not taking effect

Tags: jquery-select2-4

I am in process of upgrading select2 version 3.5.1 to 4.0. I required to use query method for mandate.

There are two specific problem arises

1. minimumInputLength is not taking effect
2. When user focus searchbox, The past results are displayed with Searching.. is first item. (If I assign empty result then it resolves the problem but then it displays No results found message)

Please refer to my code snippet below.

```
var self = this, $view = $(view);

        $.fn.select2.amd.require(['select2/data/array', 'select2/utils', 'select2/data/minimumInputLength'], function (ArrayData, Utils, MinimumInputLength) {

            function CustomData($element, options) {
                CustomData.__super__.constructor.call(this, $element, options);
                this.options = options;
            }

            Utils.Extend(CustomData, ArrayData);

            CustomData.prototype.query = function (params, callback) {
                //callback({ results: [] });
                self.searchText(params.term);
                q(ko.unwrap(self.qPromise)).then(function () {
                    var select2data = $.map(ko.unwrap(self.dataSource), function (obj) {
                        obj.id = obj.id || obj.Id + obj.KeyDoc;
                        obj.text = obj.text || obj.Headline;
                        return obj;
                    });
                    callback({ results: select2data });
                });
            }

            // Decorate after the adapter is built
            Utils.Decorate(CustomData, MinimumInputLength);

            $view.select2({
                dataAdapter: CustomData,
                multiple: ko.unwrap(self.multiple),
                templateResult: ko.unwrap(self.formatFunc),
                escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
                dropdownParent: $('.' + ko.unwrap(self.containerClass)),
                placeholder: ko.unwrap(self.placeHolderCaption),
                minimumInputLength: 1,
                allowClear: true
            });

        });
```

Every time I wish to assign new options in suggestion list (no cached no stored)
Please suggest workaround.

Thanks in advanced